# xcode 8 error class is unavailable use self instead

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode8

After upgrading to XCode 8, some third party library stopped compiling.

```
NSArray *validTypes = @[
    [NSString class],
    [NSNumber class],
    [NSDictionary class],
    [NSArray class],
    [NSNull class]
];
```

I am getting an error

```
`class` is unavailable, use `self` instead
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who encountered the same problem, I recommend the following method with replacing `class` to `self` across the whole project.

First, click on `search tab` and choose `find and replace with regex`

Your search regex pattern: `isKindOfClass:\[(\w+) (\w+)\]`, replace pattern: `isKindOfClass:$1.self`

[image]

Enter the values you see on the screenshot and click preview to double check yourself. You should see something similar:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by using `self` after trying different combinations.

```
NSArray *validTypes = @[
   NSString.self,
   NSNumber.self,
   NSDictionary.self,
   NSArray.self,
   NSNull.self
];
```